# express session-file-store session count not view-count

Tags: node.js, session, express-session, session-store

I am using express-session for session management in my node js application.
using session-file-store. I want to count the number of sessions, to restrict new sessions after maxAllowed sessions.

Is there any method supported for doing that? I dont want view count, I just want session count.

Comment: Does anyone even looks at my questions.. Why I am not getting response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count session using session-file-store can be done as shown below..

```
//file store parameters
var sess_options = {
path: "/tmp/sessions/",
useAsync: true
};
// sess_count variable
var sess_count = 0;

var file_store = new FileStore(sess_options);
router.use(session({
store : file_store,
resave : false,
saveUninitialized : true,
secret : 'asts123',
rolling : false,
cookie : {  httpOnly: false,
secure : true,
maxAge : 60000
}
}));

router.use(function(req, res, next) {
file_store.length(function session_count(a,len) {
sess_count = len;
console.log("Total active session count is " + sess_count);
console.log("============");
});
return next();
});
```

Comment: what is the reason for use async?